# Mocking PostAsync and other methods with Moq in UnitTest

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I was looking for a couple of days how to mock HttpClient and most of the responses suggested mocking HttpResponseMessage - specifically SendAsync.

I tried all that but every time I would get an error that 'Connection failure - machine failed to respond' which seems that HttpClient was not mocked at all.

I have something like this:

```
public string MethodINeedToTest()
{
    ...
    using(var client = new HttpClient)
   {
       var response = await client.PostAsync(url, StringContent);
       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       ...
   }
   ...
}
```

And then I try to mock it in my test:

```
var mockHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

mockHandler.Protected()
           .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
           .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));

//Here goes call to MethodINeedToTest()
```

But this does not help. I am not sure am I missing something or that I need to use HttpClient with dependency injection instead of 'using' statement?

Comment: Your code doesn’t show you mocking HttpClient, only that you mock HttpMessageHandler and then don’t even plug it into HttpClient. Also `new HttpClient` is not valid C#, and should probably be `new HttpClient(mockHandler.Object)`.

Comment: @ckuri What do you mean it is not valid C#? Also what to do with new HttpClient(mockHandler.Object)? Do I need to setup client after that? Because I am not using client inside test, I just need to mock it

Comment: I mean that `new HttpClient` wouldn’t compile as it’s missing the brackets to call the default constructor.

Comment: I forgot to add brackets. Can you see edit in my previous post?

Comment: What previous post? If you mean this one, then no there was no edit done to it.

Comment: What to do with new HttpClient(mockHandler.Object)? Do I need to setup client after that? Because I am not using client inside test, I just need to mock it

Comment: You need to change the instantiation from a) `new HttpClient()` in a normal environment, to b) `new HtppClient(mockHandler.Object)` in a test environment. One way would be to use the factory pattern, i.e. having an `interface IHttpClientFactory { HttpClient CreateClient(); }` which you inject in your service and then `using (var client = factory.CreateClient())`. In a normal environment you would have HttpClientFactory class implementing this interface which does just a), but in your tests you use a `TestHttpClientFactory` which does b).

Comment: Ok thank you for your aswer, I will try it. So it is not really possible to mock it without some kind of wrapper like this Interface you described? It is weird that some official code like client is done like that.

Comment: I don’t think so, as HttpClient has no interface which you could just directly mock.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to have the http client passed to the constructor of your class. Then you can pass  mock from outside. 
It is not very good practice nowadays for a class to hide dependencies.